# why is passing a string to an object adding parenthesis while other parameters do not have parenthesis?

Tags: python, json, flask

I created a object that takes in email, and phone number and country code
but whenever I pass the phone number it adds parenthesis and a comma.

Here is how I am passing it in.

```
 def post(self):
        args = parser.parse(user_args, request)
        firstName = args["firstName"]
        lastName = args["lastName"]
        email = args["email"]
        password = args["password"]
        confirmPassword = args["confirmPassword"]
        pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
        cpw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(confirmPassword).decode('utf-8')
        phoneNumber = args["phoneNumber"]
        acceptTerms = args["acceptTerms"]
        print("After Checking user input", phoneNumber)
        # Creating object and passing in the data
        **authy_id = Authy(email, phoneNumber, 1).CreateUser()**
        print(authy_id)
        return 'ok', 200
```

This is my Authy Object

```
class Authy:
    def __init__(self, email, phone, country_code):
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone,
        self.country_code = country_code

    def CreateUser(self):
        print("This is phone after creating object authy", self.email)
        print("This is phone after creating object authy", self.phone)
        user = authy_api.users.create(
            email=self.email,
            phone=self.phone,
            country_code=1
        )
        if user.ok():
            return user.id
        else:
            return user.errors()
```

This is a screenshot of how its looks after creating the object
[image]

The output should be like the email with no () or , but for some reason only phone number is like this.

Here is a sample of the json data I pass in

```
   "email":"test1@gmail.com",
    "password": "test123456",
    "confirmPassword": "test123456",
    "phoneNumber": "9155550555",
```

Comment: Note the comma on that line `self.phone = phone,`. It makes it one-element tuple

Comment: To verify, you could `print(type(self.phone))` after the assignment.

Comment: Under [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) you can search for "tuple" to read a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a comma after the phone initialization which was causing a type conversion to a tuple (for testing i just took the important parts of your code and it worked for me)

```
class Authy:
    def __init__(self, email, phone, country_code):
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone # there was a comma
        self.country_code = country_code

    def CreateUser(self):
        print("This is phone after creating object authy", self.email)
        print("This is phone after creating object authy", self.phone)
authy_id = Authy("test1@gmail.com", "9155550555", 1).CreateUser()
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that. It works now